# Keep a function alive until a string variable in memory within is updated by a callback function?

Tags: solidity

Provided a function can initialize a string variable in memory, is there a way to pass the variable by reference to a callback function to update said variable, then return the value in the initial function? The challenge is; I cannot call the callback function and pass the string variable as an argument at the same time.

For instance:

```
function initialFunction() public returns (string memory) {
    bytes memeory result = "{}"; // desired result after change
    uint256 lastRun; // Timestamp
    
    bytes32 request = buildRequest(address(this), this.f2.selector);
    
    lastRun = block.timestamp;
    
    while ((block.timestamp - lastRun) < 30 seconds && string(result) == "{}") {
        if (string(result) != "{}") {
            return result;
        }
        lastRun = block.timestamp;
    }   
}

function callbackFunction(string memory _result, string _newValue) public returns (string memory) {
    _result = _newValue;
}
```

I greatly appreciate your insight, thank you!